# Fuerte Installation on Workstation

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Fuerte Distribution on the "TurtleBot" netbook. My question is, do I need to install Fuerte Distribution on the workstation as well. Do I use the following link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu to install Fuerte on my workstation. In the wiki, it only mentions of electric or diamondback versions of ROS for SDK setup [http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/SDK%20Setup], not fuerte for workstation; so, this is confusing me.

What version to install on my workstation (fuerte or diamonback or electric) if I have fuerete installed on my "Turtlebot" Netbook.

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39196/fuerte-installation-on-workstation/) by [Amitosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2880/amitosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I presume you want to simultaneously run nodes on both the robot and your workstation. In that case, you need to install Fuerte on the workstation as well.

Never combine nodes compiled for different ROS distributions in the same roscore execution graph. Sometimes it may work, but it is not supported and not a good idea.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1